# Onprem DevOps server TFS2019 need to create a report for user profiles. Specifically preferred email report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, azure-devops-server-2019

As the title states. I need a report of all users preferred email settings in tfs2019.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read this -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There is no default way to get all users preferred email settings in tfs2019. You could use the following api to achieve it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)

{

    TfsConfigurationServer tcs = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("http://tfs2019:8080/tfs"));

    IIdentityManagementService ims = tcs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

    TeamFoundationIdentity tfi = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, "[Collection]\\Project Collection Valid Users", MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.ExtendedProperties);

    TeamFoundationIdentity[] ids = ims.ReadIdentities(tfi.Members, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.ExtendedProperties);


    foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity id in ids)

    {
        if (id.Descriptor.IdentityType == "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity")

        {
            Console.WriteLine(id.DisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine(id.UniqueName);
            Console.WriteLine(id.GetAttribute("Mail", null));
        }

    }

    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Comment: Have you checked my reply? Is your issue solved?